# Why is there no way to make electric field at point P zero by changing quantity and sign of charge of $q_1$?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, electric-fields

[image]

q1 = -2.4μC and q2 = 8.9 μC,  q3 = 2.3 μC, d is 6.2cm.

Suppose that we want to make electric field at point P zero. We leave everything about q2 and q3 as they were before, but we are allowed to change the sign and magnitude of charge of q1. (distance and d cannot be changed for every charge)

But it is told that there is no way to make electric field at point P zero just by changing q1. Why is it like that?

All my calculations seem to show that it is indeed possible to make electric field at point P zero... using Coulomb's law..

Comment: And what was your calculation? I suppose your condition for zeroing the field was $q_3/d^2 + q_2/d^2 + q1/(2d)^2 = 0$, which gives a unique value for $q_1$ given any $q_2$ and $q_3$. I suggest you think about what happens if you consider the analogous problem except there is no $q_1$ and you control $q_3$ instead of $q_1$. Image which way a charge at P would go without doing math, and how you could get it to go nowhere without changing $q_2$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you are working in the plane, the electric field, which is a vector quantity, is specified by two numbers, ie its components. The condition that the electric field be zero is, hence, equivalent to satisfying two equations, one for each component. Given you have only one number to change, q1, you shouldn't expect in general to be able to satisfy both equations.

In this example in particular, as the line joining q2 and P is perpendicular to the line joining q3 and P, by considering the components of the electric field (at P) along these two lines one obtains one equation for each component in terms only of q1 and either q2 or q3. As the problem is symmetrical under simultaneous reflection in the line q1-P and exchange of the charges q2 and q3, the two equations are the same but with q2 and q3 swapped. Now one can see  why no single value of q1 can, in general, make the electric field vanish: the equation for one component of the field can be satisfied (ie that component can be made to vanish with a suitable choice of q1) but the chosen value of q1 will not satisfy the second equation unless q3 is equal to q2.

Answer (score 0):

You are required to make the electric field $\mathbf{\vec E}$ at $P = 0$. i.e. $E_x = E_y = 0$. Imposing these conditions and using Coulomb's law, you will get $q_1 = -2 \sqrt{2} q_2$ and $q_1 = -2 \sqrt{2} q_3$ which is not possible since $q_2 \neq q_3$.